# How to handle questions which change / evolve / involve troubleshooting?

Tags: discussion, comments, edits, best-practices

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

This happens to me a *lot*, especially on ServerFault. I'll look for some examples from SF and post them later, but for now, [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596291/jquery-html-grab-calling-a-controller-action-using-javascript-ruby-on-rails) is what causes me to ask:

What's the best way to handle questions which start out asking one thing and then evolve into a different matter entirely?

The same basic quandry, I believe, applies to: What's the best way to handle questions which are essentially just troubleshooting, and will require a lot of back and forth?

What I mean is, in the StackOverflow question I linked to, Zind was asking how to use jQuery to submit an AJAX request. But as I worked with him via my answer, switching my answer from jQuery to Prototype, it became clear to me that his issue wasn't jQuery/Prototype/AJAX, it was a cross domain iFrame scripting issue.

On ServerFault, often people will ask questions like "*x* isn't working, here are some logs and things I have tried". I find I don't have enough information to answer the question outright but want to provide suggestions/starting points/requests for additional information.

In both these two cases I post my suggestions / thoughts / requests for information as an *answer*, and ask the question's author to try my suggestions/code/provide info and edit their question. I then edit *my* question based on the additional information.

Is this the best way to handle this? Should requests for information or suggestions on things to try be comments rather than answers? If the core issue of a question changes drastically, should a new question be posted, or is drastic editing of questions and answers to pinpoint an evolving situation OK?

**EDIT:** Some examples from ServerFault:

- [Apache error with suEXEC only](https://serverfault.com/questions/128809/apache-error-with-suexec-only/)
- [Why is this mod_rewrite RewriteRule directive not working in the .htaccess file?](https://serverfault.com/questions/77347/why-is-this-mod-rewrite-rewriterule-directive-not-working-in-the-htaccess-file/)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions

Comment: @Jon: Thanks - I never would have found that! Sounds like my question probably is a duplicate

Comment: Yeah, non-searchable titles ftl. Sorry about that, it looks like you put a lot of work into this post.

Comment: @Jon: No problem, my question is clearly a duplicate of his, and maybe the time I took to write my question will help the next guy find the answer :-)

Comment: For anyone finding this (now very old) question, **here's [an idea on this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions/75987#75987) now that we have chat**...